# Is there are way that model methods can work with variable with out them being explicitly passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables

I know this sounds like a ridiculous question but I trying to solve a chalange given by an potential employer. I have a schema and a couple of models with their methods. Almost all the methods have no variables passed in. Meaning none of the methods look like this:

```
def this_is_my_method(variable)
  #stuff
end
```

or

```
def this_is_my_method variable
  #stuff
end
```

but there are methods that are clearly working with variables like this:

```
def build_address
  if variable
    # do something
  end
end
```

Is there a RoR way that a model method will just know about certain parameters or variables in certain situations?

So if my controller was recieving params that looked like this:

```
?my_method[begin]=1&my_method[end]=5
```

would the model method "my_method" know what "begin" and "end" where?

```
def my_method
  if self.begin == self.end
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

Comment: Create that variable as attribute accessor.........when you want to pass assigned to object else you will get nil.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that a model method has access to all the attributes (and other methods) of that model instance.

So (for example) this would be a valid model method.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
  end

end
```

This is taking an attribute `user.first_name` and an attribute `user.last_name` and combining them to create a new method `user.full_name`

EDIT as @Sanket has suggested you can pass values into a model if you make them attribute accessor...

```
def SomeController < ApplicationController

  def some_controller_method

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @user.begin = params[:begin]
    @user.end = params[:end]
    @user.some_model_method
  end
end

def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :begin, :end
  def some_model_method
    if self.begin == self.end
      # do something
    else
      # do something else
    end
  end
end
```

Although to be frank I'd rather just pass the values in as method arguments.

Comment: Ok, revised my answer... if I haven't got your question fully understood let me know.